# How can I represent a number as a chromosome in a genetic algorithm?

Tags: genetic-algorithm

I want to use a genetic algorithm to solve a simple system of two linear equations with two variables.  This is mainly to help me get a better understanding of how they work.

Everything seems pretty simple, but I am unsure how to encode possible solutions in the chromosomes for this problem.

I will have two variables which I want to encode in a chromosome to represent a solution.  If each variable is can be represented an 8-bit number, would I make a 16-bit binary encoded chromosome (A string of 1's and 0's).

I am just not quite sure how that would work.  If two parents are selected for breeding, how would randomly selecting genes from the binary string result in a possibly better solution?  This is why I don't think a binary string would work, so any answers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You don't just randomly select bits from the two parents.  You go through the bits in order.  If both parents have a 1 in the same bit position, the gene is passed on.  If both parents have a zero in the same bit position, the gene is not passed on.  Only if one parent has a 1 and the other a zero, does random selection come into play.

Comment: Thank you for your response, if this were an answer I would mark it as correct!

Comment: What Gilbert LeBlanc describes is called UniformCrossover. I would not recommend using it since it is very disruptive and does not preserve larger fragments of one parent. A single point crossover is recommended first choice. There you select a crossover point in your strings and choose the first half from the first parent and the second half from the second parent. The point is chosen randomly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not use the numbers as numbers? You don't have to use binary encoding in a GA. There are mutation and crossover operators working well for real-valued encodings. As you say it's a learning example.. I would recommend you try both approaches, the real-valued encoding should be much quicker to converge.

For binary encoding I would use Single Point Crossover and Bit flip Mutation. For real-valued encoding I would use Blend-Alpha-Beta Crossover (BLX-a-b) or Simulated Binary Crossover (SBX) and Normal Distributed Mutation. You can try some of these and many more operators on the SingleObjectiveTestFunctions in [HeuristicLab](http://dev.heuristiclab.com).

Comment: HeuristicLab looks like an amazing piece of software.  I am downloading it now.  I will certainly try real valued encoding.  Thank you for your answer!